# How does the OS understand C strings if its encoding is implementation-defined?

Tags: c++, c, string, unicode

I read that C strings are just byte strings and the encoding used to store text is implementation-defined. If this is so, then how does the operating system know how to interpret a string when we make system call to open a file or execute a program? I noticed that the fopen function in the stdio.h takes a C string.

The other part of my question, who decides the encoding that C strings should use? Is this something decided arbitrarily by the compiler, or is it decided by the operating system?

Comment: The OS API will exactly define how to make system calls and the arguments required.

Comment: Any sensible implementation will use the encoding that the OS expects. Anything else would lead to madness. Or, at least, a translation layer between the application and the OS.

Comment: The final decision of what encoding a C implementation will use is made by the people who write or produce the C implementation (and they may provide some switches or other configuration options to let their users select it). Most often, they will use a character encoding that is compatible with the target operating system. If they do not, the standard C library for the implementation must translate between the implementation’s strings passed in `fopen` and other routines and the operating system’s strings used in the operating system routines that the library calls.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I thought the C standard library is implemented by the operating system? Doesn't that mean that a particular C implementation must use the encoding the OS expects. If this is so, is there a way to obtain a comprehensive list of the encodings used by various OSes?

Comment: Why do you think an OS needs to understand strings? An OS needs to compare strings (to look up files etc). This does not really require any kind of understanding.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. What if I wanted to access a file created using a program compiled with a different setting than the one in which the program that created the file used? Since the encodings could be different the byte strings might end up being different even though they encode the same text.

For example, the string "myfile.txt" in a program compiled with msvc could have a byte sequence different from the same string in a program compiled with mingw.

Comment: `the string "myfile.txt"` What *is* the string "myfile.txt"? There is no such thing. There is a sequence of bytes that, when interpreted as ASCII, reads "myfile.txt". There is another sequence of bytes that, when interpreted as EBCDIC, reads "myfile.txt". The OS doesn't need to prefer one interpretation over another or require valid ASCII or valid EBCDIC or anything of the sort. It may well require with any sequence of bytes you pass it. Then if you have two compilers and two user environments that use these encodings, you will have a situation where a file created in one environment

Comment: with a program built with one compiler will not be accessible in another environment with a program built with another compiler, under a name that looks the same to their respective users. So what? This is not a hypothetical situation, such things do happen. Try working in Linux under two user accounts, one in UTF-8 and the other in ISO8859-1, and you will get exactly that (with accented characters, not basic ASCII). A file name is a sequence of bytes in Linux. Some other OSes require strings in a specific encoding, and this is OK too.

Comment: @SamuelOkechukwu: A C implementation is “particular set of software, running in a particular translation environment under particular control options, that performs translation of programs for, and supports execution of functions in, a particular execution environment” (C 2018 3.12). So essentially a C implementation is everything you need to compile and execute C programs—the compiler, the standard C library, the operating system, and the hardware…

Comment: … Many Unix-based C implementations use the [GNU C Library](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/), so it is neither part of the operating system nor part of the compiler. But it is often distributed with the operating system and/or with the compiler. The various folks involved talk to each other, either directly or through drafting standards and documentation or through but reporting systems or various forums, to make these things work together.

Answer (score 1):

Your OS and/or C/C++ standard library expect a certain encoding in the APIs they provide. They can also provide ways to change the encoding (certain `std::locale`s on Windows enabling UTF-8 in file paths, etc).

The compiler may either trust you on the encoding (preserve the source file encoding in the strings), or may change the encoding to a one appropriate for the target OS.

All of this is mostly theory. ASCII is ubiquitous, so both the sources and the APIs almost always use some superset of ASCII. Most of the time this superset is UTF-8, though Windows has some quirks (the terminal expecting some weird encoding instead of UTF-8 by default (last checked on MinGW on Windows 7, not sure if still the case), the standard library functions not understanding UTF-8 paths by default (at least in the old C standard library some MinGW versions use), etc).

Some compilers let you customize the encoding, e.g. GCC has `-finput-charset=A -fexec-charset=B` which converts from A to B. This option doesn't work in Clang though (as of Clang 14), so you shouldn't rely on it.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand now. I was getting confused because I thought the encoding to be used is decided by the compiler.

Comment: @SamuelOkechukwu You're welcome. In theory, it is decided by the compiler. I haven't seen compilers using this power by default though.